# Creating cron tab to notify ram usage using python

Tags: python-3.x, cron

My computer freezes due to unused applications and unclosed chrome tabs clogging up all the RAM. So, I am trying to create a cron job using a python script to notify me when RAM usage exceeds 90%, so that I can close all the unused applications.

I have tried looking for some answers as to how I can achieve this.

Here is the cron job command:

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/karan/Documents/notes/python/NotifyRamUsage.py
```

And here is the python script:

```py
import psutil
import os

ramUsed = psutil.virtual_memory().percent
threshold = 90

if ramUsed > threshold:
    os.system("notify-send '{}% ram used. Shut down unused processes.'".format(ramUsed))
```

I tried this with 10% as the threshold so that I could see if it was indeed working, however, nothing happens.
The python script runs perfectly when running from the console.
OS is Ubuntu, and python version is 3.6.
I have also given executable permissions to the file.
What is it that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Comment: I edited my answer see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when trying to invoke python scripts from cron. What I ended up doing was to create a small shell/python script and invoke it from cron instead, like so:

`my_script.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import psutil
import os

ramUsed = psutil.virtual_memory().percent
threshold = 90

if ramUsed > threshold:
    os.system("notify-send '{}% ram used. Shut down unused processes.'".format(ramUsed))
```

Or a true shell script like so:

`my_script.sh`

```
python3 /home/karan/Documents/notes/python/NotifyRamUsage.py
```

Give them execution permision with `chmod o+x` and then invoke one of them from cron

`*/1 * * * * my_script.sh`

Hope it helps :)

**EDIT**

Also maybe the reason your popup doesn't show up is because your script should be executed as a specific user. Take a look a this article which explains how to do it.

http://www.lostsaloon.com/technology/how-to-run-cron-jobs-as-a-specific-user/

Comment: I tried using it. The shell script is executing my python script, however, I didn't get any popups. To verify that my python script was, in fact, being executed, I wrote a log file with ram usage, which was being written fine. It is just that I am not getting any popups.